Image update in Custom Tkinter
I'm making a simple weather app in Custom Tkinter usimg OpenWeather's API, and I'm having trouble updating the weather icon when the user enters another city from the list. I'm still working on the app, excuse the messy code.
import requests
from customtkinter import *
from PIL import Image


app = CTk()
app.title('Turtle')
app.geometry('1000x500')





c_img = CTkImage(light_image=Image.open('cloudy.jpg'),size=(100, 100))
msg_label = CTkLabel(app, text="", text_color='Blue', font=('Arial', 25, 'bold'))
temp_label = CTkLabel(app, text="", text_color='Blue', font=('Arial', 25, 'bold'))
condition_label = CTkLabel(app, text="", text_color='Blue', font=('Arial', 25, 'bold'))
wind_label = CTkLabel(app, text="", text_color='Blue', font=('Arial', 25, 'bold'))
alert_label = CTkLabel(app, text="", text_color='Blue', font=('Arial', 25, 'bold'))



filename1 = "cloudy.jpg"




name_entry = CTkEntry(app, font=('Arial', 25, 'bold'), corner_radius=32)

ecity = ""




def update_weather(event):
 
 filename1 = 'cloudy.jpg'
 ecity = ""
 ecity = name_entry.get()


 #Fetch weather information from OpenWeatherMap API
 api = '928c56960d62b32ac062752c50a07679'  

 cityid = '6094817'
 
 if ecity.lower() == "mecca" :
        cityid = '104515'
 elif ecity.lower() == "medina":
        cityid = '109223'
 elif ecity.lower() == "tokyo":
        cityid = '1850147'
 elif ecity.lower() == "dubai":
        cityid = '292224'
 elif ecity.lower() == "new york":
        cityid = '5128581'
 elif ecity.lower() == "paris":
        cityid = '6455259'
 elif ecity.lower() == 'london':
        cityid = '1006984'
 elif ecity.lower() == "shanghai":
        cityid = '1796236'
 elif ecity.lower() == 'ottawa':
        cityid = '6094817'  #Ottawa city ID

 apiurl = f'''http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={cityid}&appid={api}&units=metric'''
 response = requests.get(apiurl)

 
 if response.status_code == 200:
     data = response.json()
     cityname = data['name']
     temperature = data['main']['temp']
     condition = data['weather'][0]['description']
     windspeed = data['wind']['speed']
     alert = data.get('alerts')
    
    
     print(f"Weather for {cityname}")
     print("Temperature:", temperature)
     print("Wind speed", windspeed)
     print("Condition:", condition)
     print(data)
    
     msg_label.configure(text=f"Weather for {cityname}: ", font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
     temp_label.configure(text=f"Temperature: {temperature}°C", font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
     condition_label.configure(text=f"Condition: {condition}", font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
     wind_label.configure(text=f"Wind speed: {windspeed}m/s", font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
     alert_label.configure(text=f"Weather alerts: {alert}", font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
    
    
 else:
     print("Failed to fetch weather information.")

 if 'rain' in condition.lower():
      filename1 = 'rainy.jpeg'
 elif 'light rain' in condition.lower():
      filename1 = 'rainy.jpeg'
 elif 'overcast clouds' in condition.lower():
         filename1 = 'cloudy.jpg'
 elif 'broken clouds' in condition.lower():
      filename1 = 'cloudy.jpg'
 elif 'sunny' in condition.lower():
         filename1 = 'sunny.png'
 elif 'sun' in condition.lower():
        filename1 = 'sunny.png'
 elif 'thunder storm' in condition.lower():
      filename1 = 'thunderstorm.png'
 elif 'snowy' in condition.lower():
      filename1 = 'snowy.png'
 elif 'snow' in condition.lower():
      filename1 = 'snowy.png'






 image_label = CTkLabel(app, image=c_img, text="")
 image_label.pack()

name_entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event: update_weather(event))



update_weather(True)
msg_label.pack()
temp_label.pack()
condition_label.pack()
wind_label.pack()
alert_label.pack()
name_entry.pack()

app.mainloop()



I tried using a CTkLabel instead:
c_img = CTkImage(light_image=Image.open('cloudy.jpg'),size=(100, 100))

###Code###

c_img.configure(light_image = Image.open(filename1))

It updated, but only once, and printed out the image to the window.

To update an image you should not just modify the filename (which won't change anything), you should replace the lines where you replace filename1 by something like this: c_img.configure(light_image="image_path")

How did u know number? cityid = '6094817'

That's OpenWeather's API ID for each city

You should create image_label once instead of creating new one whenever update_weather() is executed.  And you need to update c_img inside the function:
...

c_img = CTkImage(light_image=Image.open('cloudy.jpg'),size=(100, 100))
# create image_label here
image_label = CTkLabel(app, text="", image=c_img)
...

def update_weather(event):
    ...
    # update image of c_img
    c_img.configure(light_image=Image.open(filename1))
    # don't create new label
    #image_label = CTkLabel(app, image=c_img, text="")
    #image_label.pack()

...

update_weather(True)
image_label.pack()
...



I'm having trouble updating the weather icon when the user enters
another city from the list.

Folllowing by @acw1668.

On line 24. comment out #filename1 = "p2.png"

On line 118, add c_img.configure(light_image=Image.open(filename1))
inside update_weather function. So, you can see updates.
    elif 'snow' in condition.lower():
         filename1 = 'snowy.png'


 c_img.configure(light_image=Image.open(filename1))  #<== add this



Screenshot:

Btw, you need more than 50 images, because of this condition = data['weather'][0]['description']
